# What are the advantages of including Jinja2 with Flask on GAE instead of using GAE version?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

Every boilerplate project and tutorial I have found for Flask on GAE includes a separate version of Jinja2, but GAE Python 2.7 includes Jinja2 2.6 by default and including it in app.yaml is much more convenient:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: 2.6
```

Are there any advantages of including a separate version of Jinja2 instead of using the GAE version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, no. I mean, if you wanted a version of `jinja2` that isn't available on AppEngine, you could include it custom, but as long as you're not picky about versions, just use what's already available.

Comment: Just to add, 2.6 is the latest version; 2.7 isn't released yet, as per the [change log](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/changelog/).  So you aren't missing anything if you use the bundled version.

Comment: Thanks! Merry Christmas/Happy Holidays!